# How can i import vtk in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, vtk

I'm trying to use VTK directly in PyCharm (vtkpython-7.0.0-Windows-64bit.exe)

After changing the interpreter references I still can not import vtk.
When I want to load the vtkpython.exe directly i have an error.

[image: error_screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

May be it is late but you can try this:

1. Install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)  as the interpreter for python.
2. Launch command-prompt or terminal and type for python 2.7

   `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda`
3. Upon completion you can type for python 3.4

`conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda`

4. `activate py27` or `activate py34` (on windows)

`source activate` (on Mac)

to activate the terminal you want. Then you can install the vtk library on this terminal.

5. Type `conda install vtk` and Proceed with yes to install vtk. Then you can use `import vtk`on Pycharm. This is just one of the methods.

I would like to thank this fantastic blogger [PyScience](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/) where i learnt this from. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `vtk` in python, you don't need to set it as the interpreter. Your interpreter is still the python installation. `vtk` is connected to your python installation. If you want to use it, you have to import it with `import vtk`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Pycharm doesn't find 'import vtk'

Normally I use Python 3. If I open the vtkpython.exe this is compiled for Python 2.7. Could this maybe be the problem?

Comment: That is most definitely the problem. You need to install `vtk` for the python version you are using. `vtk`'s latest version is `7.0` and it is compatible with python 3.4/3.5

Comment: It wasn't succesful. Now i downloaded the full Python(x,y) package where this was done automatically. Now it works!